# C# Populating listview with data in while statement

Tags: c#, xml, listbox

I got a frustrating c# problem. I have this XML data:

```
<entries>
  <schedule>
    <flight>UAL9858</flight>
    <dep>San Francisco, CA (KSFO)</dep>
    <deptime>07:00:00</deptime>
    <arr>(URSS)</arr>
    <arrtime>20:00:00</arrtime>
    <ac>744</ac>
    <dur>15:15:00</dur>
    <cat>1</cat>
    <id>28858</id>
  </schedule>
  <schedule>
    <flight>UAL9857</flight>
    <dep>San Francisco, CA (KSFO)</dep>
    <deptime>07:00:00</deptime>
    <arr>(URSS)</arr>
    <arrtime>20:00:00</arrtime>
    <ac>777</ac>
    <dur>15:15:00</dur>
    <cat>1</cat>
    <id>28857</id>
  </schedule>
  <schedule>
    <flight>SKW6289</flight>
    <dep>San Francisco, CA (KSFO)</dep>
    <deptime>19:38:00</deptime>
    <arr>Albuquerque, NM (KABQ)</arr>
    <arrtime>23:04:00</arrtime>
    <ac>CRJ</ac>
    <dur>02:26:00</dur>
    <cat>1</cat>
    <id>10413</id>
  </schedule>
</entries>
```

Now i have a column for each node(dep, deptime, arr, arrtime,ac,dur,cat,id), and I want to populate each row with the text content between each , with each entry below that being in its own column. This way the entire xml document appears in a table format. I am using the following format to populate a textbox with the read xml information(for debugging purposes):

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fullURL))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.IsStartElement())
                    {

                        switch (reader.Name)
                        {

                            case "flight":
                                var flight = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(flight + " | ");
                                break;
                            case "dep":
                                var dep = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(dep + " | ");
                                break;
                            case "deptime":
                                var deptime = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(deptime + " | ");
                                break;
                            case "arr":
                                var arr = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(arr + " | ");
                                break;
                            case "arrtime":
                                var arrtime = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(arrtime + " | ");
                                break;
                            case "ac":
                                var ac = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(ac + " | ");
                                break;
                            case "dur":
                                var dur = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(dur + " | ");
                                break;
                            case "cat":
                                var cat = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(cat + " | ");
                                break;
                            case "id":
                                var id = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(id + " | ");
                                break;
```

How would i accomplish this task?

Comment: ASP.net, WinForms, WPF? Which are you working with here for your UI?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Schedule{
  string flight {get; set; }
string dep {get; set; }
string deptime {get; set; }
string arr {get; set; }
string arrtime {get; set; }
string ac {get; set; }
string dur {get; set; }
string cat {get; set; }
string id {get; set; }
}

public List<Schedule> Schedules = new List<Schedule>();

Schedule current;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fullURL))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    current = new Schedule();
                    if (reader.IsStartElement())
                    {

                        switch (reader.Name)
                        {

                            case "flight":
                                current.flight = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                break;
                            case "dep":
                                current.dep = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                break;
                            case "deptime":
                                current.deptime = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(deptime + " | ");
                            case "arr":
                                current.arr = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                break;
                            case "arrtime":
                                current.arrtime = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                break;
                            case "ac":
                                var ac = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                textBox3.AppendText(ac + " | ");
                                break;
                            case "dur":
                                current.dur = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                break;
                            case "cat":
                                current.cat = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                break;
                            case "id":
                                current.Id = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                break;

Schedule.Add(current)
}
}
}
```

once you have your list of Schedule populated you can display it however you like.

Comment: how would this populate the listview though?